# Problem building Postgis 1.5.x for Pg 8.4 on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

Here are things installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-8.4 libpq5 libpq-dev
```

Here is a past to my config.out: http://pastebin.com/8Nk6pr96

And, here are some hints I got from IRC (names concealed)

```
< foo> it's NOT failing to find libpq.
< foo> libpq is present, but not compilable without adding a boatload of other -l flags
< foo> and postgis' configure doesn't let you specify that via LIBS
< foo> his paste contains the config.out, which shows this
```

The configure dies with this, `configure: error: could not find libpq`

I intend to install postgis for mapfish :)

Comment: And your problem is ...?

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, why would you bother to compile your own postgis when the same version is available from the ubuntu maverick universe package repository?

If you are really bent on building it yourself, I would recommend checking out the source package for postgis on ubuntu. It will have a debian/rules file that describes it's build procedure. You can download the source package to the current directory with "apt-get source postgis" assuming your apt repos include the universe repo.

Comment: I just realized that you are running 9.10, not 10.10. I would still have a look at the source package for postgis on maverick for hints.